# How to iterate arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

This question might be a simple iteration, but I'm stuck in the logic.

I have an array of data which needs to be iterated based on id and code and remove the data in the following scenarios.

And, this will not be applicable if all the data has same ID.

** Data might have only one ID or two ID's. Not more than two **

Here is the Case Scenarios, From the below data,

1. There are two different code named "GOOGLE" with different id (381, 378) - **Valid**
2. There are two different code named "FACEBOOK" with different id (381, 378) - **Valid**
3. If there is no different ID's in the data (meaning all data has same id), return all the arrays - **Valid**
4. There is a code named "TWITTER" and "INSTAGRAM" which is not present in another id - **INVALID**.

In Case 4, I wanted to remove these two data based on case 4.

```
{ "id" : 378, "code" : "TWITTER", "comment" : "zeeer" }, 

{ "id" : 385, "code" : "INSTAGRAM", "comment" : "hgtff" },
```

I tried something below and it was working for the Case 1, 2 and 4. **Not working for Case 3.**

```js
const data = [ 
  { "id" : 381, "code" : "GOOGLE", "comment" : "ffff" }, 
  { "id" : 381, "code" : "FACEBOOK", "comment" : "fff" }, 
  { "id" : 378, "code" : "TWITTER", "comment" : "zeeer" }, 
  { "id" : 378, "code" : "GOOGLE", "comment" : "rferer" }, 
  { "id" : 378, "code" : "FACEBOOK", "comment" : "fefehh" },
  { "id" : 385, "code" : "INSTAGRAM", "comment" : "hgtff" },
  { "id" : 378, "code" : "ORKUT", "comment" : "abcd" },
  { "id" : 381, "code" : "ORKUT", "comment" : "abcd" },
];

let result = data.filter(({id,code}) => !!data.find(obj => 
 obj.code === code && obj.id !== id
));

console.log("result", result);

/* Not Working for Case 3 */

const data2 = [ 
  { "id" : 381, "code" : "GOOGLE", "comment" : "ffff" }, 
  { "id" : 381, "code" : "FACEBOOK", "comment" : "fff" }, 
];

let result2 = data2.filter(({id,code}) => !!data2.find(obj => 
 obj.code === code && obj.id !== id
));

console.log("result 2", result2); // Throwing Empty Response, Expected is to return all the two arrays as it has same ID (381).
```

Comment: **Typo/Logical Error?** Change `!!data2.find(obj => ` to `!!data.find(obj => `

Comment: And how is it about Typescript?

Comment: @Tushar, I just have two set of data for showing the empty response. That's why have two different  variables i.e data, data2. Just for showing purpose

Comment: @dfsq, I didn't get you. As I'm using angular 7, so I said typescript.

Comment: @UI_Dev Your question would be exactly the same if you asked about JavaScript, hence it does not have anything to do with TypeScript: You're not using any TypeScript-specific feature in what you've shown.

Comment: Oh Sorry, solution with javascript also fine for me..

Comment: Edited the question as well.. Sorry for the miscommunication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter logic is not handling the case #3 anyhow, so to achieve that functionality you'll have to add additional checks if that case is true for the given data.

Example code, for **only** checking if all given data has the same "id"

```
if (data.reduce((prev, cur, _, array) => prev || cur.id !== array[0].id, false) === false) { // Handle case #3 }
```

EDIT: JavaScript snippet.

```js
const findTheItemsYouWant = (data) => {
    // Extra check to check for case #3, where every "id" is the same.
    if (data.reduce((prev, cur, _, array) => prev || cur.id !== array[0].id, false) === false) {
        // All "id"s are the same - return the original input Array.
        return data
    }
    // Otherwise, filter result to only objects that pass the predicate:
    // Array must contain an object with equal "code" and different "id".
    return data.filter(({id, code}) =>
        data.find(obj =>
            obj.code === code && obj.id !== id
        ) !== undefined
    )
}
const data = [ 
    { "id" : 381, "code" : "GOOGLE", "comment" : "ffff" }, 
    { "id" : 381, "code" : "FACEBOOK", "comment" : "fff" }, 
    { "id" : 378, "code" : "TWITTER", "comment" : "zeeer" }, 
    { "id" : 378, "code" : "GOOGLE", "comment" : "rferer" }, 
    { "id" : 378, "code" : "FACEBOOK", "comment" : "fefehh" },
    { "id" : 385, "code" : "INSTAGRAM", "comment" : "hgtff" },
    { "id" : 378, "code" : "ORKUT", "comment" : "abcd" },
    { "id" : 381, "code" : "ORKUT", "comment" : "abcd" },
];
console.log("result", findTheItemsYouWant(data));

const data2 = [ 
    { "id" : 381, "code" : "GOOGLE", "comment" : "ffff" }, 
    { "id" : 381, "code" : "FACEBOOK", "comment" : "fff" }, 
];
console.log("result 2", findTheItemsYouWant(data2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most computationally cheap solution, however I recommend moving your logic into a function and simply checking whether there is only one ID in the array first and returning the original array. And if that is not the case, run your logic afterwards:

```js
function cleanData(data) {
  const uniqueIds = data
    .map(obj => obj.id)
    .filter((value, index, self) => {
      return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    });

  if (uniqueIds.length === 1) {
    return data;
  }

  return data.filter(({ id, code }) =>
    data.find(obj => obj.code === code && obj.id !== id)
  );
}

const data = [
  { id: 381, code: 'GOOGLE', comment: 'ffff' },
  { id: 381, code: 'FACEBOOK', comment: 'fff' },
  { id: 378, code: 'TWITTER', comment: 'zeeer' },
  { id: 378, code: 'GOOGLE', comment: 'rferer' },
  { id: 378, code: 'FACEBOOK', comment: 'fefehh' },
  { id: 385, code: 'INSTAGRAM', comment: 'hgtff' },
  { id: 378, code: 'ORKUT', comment: 'abcd' },
  { id: 381, code: 'ORKUT', comment: 'abcd' }
];

let result = cleanData(data);

console.log('Result:', result);

const data2 = [
  { id: 381, code: 'GOOGLE', comment: 'ffff' },
  { id: 381, code: 'FACEBOOK', comment: 'fff' }
];

result = cleanData(data2);

console.log('Result 2:', result);
```